# I am creating a class to calculate a cylinder and a method is giving me a issue

Tags: python

I have been creating a program to calculate a bunch of geometric shapes and I got this error while running the code bellow it:

```
    def surface_area(self):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here is the code:

```
class Cylinder():
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height
        
    def volume(self):
        return pi * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
    
    def diameter(self):
        volume = pi * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
        return 2 * sqrt(self.volume / (pi * self.height)
                        
    def surface_area(self):
        return (2 * pi * self.radius * self.height) + (2 * pi * (self.radius ** 2))
                        
    def base_area(self):
        return pi * self.radius ** 2
    
    def lateral_surface_area(self):
        return 2 * pi * self.radius * self.height
```

if someone can help that will be amazing.

Comment: You're missing a `)`, on the `return 2 * sqrt(...` line above that.

Comment: You have missed a bracket in the last line of diameter function

Comment: There‘s a bracket missing in `diameter()`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a missing bracket in your code

```
def diameter(self):
    volume = pi * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
    return 2 * sqrt(self.volume / (pi * self.height)
#                  ^               ^               ^       ^
#                  |             open 2         close 2    |
#                open                                open never closed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple mistake, in your `diameter` function the last line is missing a bracket, see `return 2 * sqrt(self.volume / (pi * self.height)`, should be this `return 2 * sqrt(self.volume / (pi * self.height))`.

Notice the second bracket at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing bracket here at line 11

```
return 2 * sqrt(self.volume / (pi * self.height)
```

Answer (score -1):

class cylinder:

```
pi = 3.14

def __init__(self, height, radius):
    self.radius = radius
    self.height = height

def volume(self):
    volume = self.height*3.14*self.radius**2
    print('Volume of the cylinder is {}'. format(volume))
    

def surface_area(self):
    area = 2*3.14*(self.radius)*(self.height)
    print('Surface area of the cylinder is {}'. format(area))
```

c = cylinder(2,3)
c.surface_area()